# How can I make custom LEGO packaging?

Tags: manufacturing, customization

How can I print high-quality custom packaging for a custom-made model?

I am aware of [DesignByMe](http://designbyme.lego.com/en-us/default.aspx). But as many of you know, the pieces for that are limited, as are the options for making your own box.

If I have six images that I can apply to each face, what techniques can I use for getting the images on a real box, and where do you recommend getting a box most like those sold by LEGO?

Comment: Printing companies would be your best bet, although not many will print singles.

Comment: Since you mentioned DesignByMe - You should know that LEGO is discontinuing that program on January 16, 2012 so if you do want to take advantage of it you only have 10 days from now. http://designbyme.lego.com/en-us/FAQ/default.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a search for [custom box design](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=custom+box+design) although I doubt they'd make small volumes either. It would [look very professional](http://www.allpackco.com/custom_corrugated.html), though.

What I've seen fans selling [custom kits](http://www.blokbricks.com/) doing is using simple white boxes with stickers on them. Usually the buyers are more interested in the contents anyway. Sticker printing shouldn't be a problem (as it's going to be put on cardboard a simple inkjet-sticker sheet should do), and I assume plain white boxes shouldn't be too hard to find.

An laternative would be to print your images on cardboard which you can fold yourself, but then you'll need to think properly about placement of images. If the cardboard is thin, you can use it as an outer shell for an inner white box which would be more solid. [3mm cardboard may be overkill](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-custom-storage-boxes-for-CD-shelf/), but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 4):

For our lead singer's birthday, his sister created this lego kit [image: Metaltech lego] which came in two boxes, one for the band, one for the...accessory. All in their own baggies.

She printed the images onto normal paper, then glued these to thin cardboard boxes.

They came out looking absolutely brilliant - feel free to compare with the real thing at [www.metaltech.me](http://www.metaltech.me)

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer as well. Not sure if I'm going to change this to the accepted answer though...